# model.predict is not a function while using TensorflowJS

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have scoured the far reaches of the internet like the following:

- https://beta.observablehq.com/@cedrickchee/load-and-serve-a-pre-trained-model-in-javascript-with-tensor
- https://github.com/google/emoji-scavenger-hunt
- https://medium.com/tensorflow/a-gentle-introduction-to-tensorflow-js-dba2e5257702

All of them have a similar way of predicting from the model:

```
model.predict()
```

According to the docs, it should return an object with the predictions in it.  However, I am always getting a `is not a function` error.  Below is a snippet of code that I have.

```
constructor() {
    console.time('Loading of model');
    this.mobileNet = new MobileNet();
    this.mobileNet.loadMobilenet();
    console.timeEnd('Loading of model');
}

const result = tfc.tidy(() => {

    // tfc.fromPixels() returns a Tensor from an image element.
    const raw = tfc.fromPixels(this.CANVAS).toFloat();
    const cropped = this.cropImage(raw);
    const resized = tfc.image.resizeBilinear(cropped, [this.IMAGE_SIZE, this.IMAGE_SIZE])

    // Normalize the image from [0, 255] to [-1, 1].
    const offset = tfc.scalar(127);
    const normalized = resized.sub(offset).div(offset);

    // Reshape to a single-element batch so we can pass it to predict.
    const batched = normalized.expandDims(0);

    console.log(batched)

    // Make a prediction through mobilenet.
    return this.mobileNet.model.predict(batched).dataSync();
});
```

**EDIT**
Included the code for the model

```
import * as tfc from '@tensorflow/tfjs-core';
import { loadFrozenModel } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-converter';

const MODEL_URL = '/assets/project-gaea/models/web_model.pb';
const WEIGHTS_URL = '/assets/project-gaea/models/weights_manifest.json';

const INPUT_NODE_NAME = 'input';
const OUTPUT_NODE_NAME = 'MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1';
const PREPROCESS_DIVISOR = tfc.scalar(255 / 2);

export default class MobileNet {
    constructor() { }

    async loadMobilenet() {
        this.model = await loadFrozenModel(MODEL_URL, WEIGHTS_URL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the code where the model or the mobileNet variable is created?

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel, included the code snippet for the model

Comment: did you try to console.log the model before predicting? And are you making sure the prediction is happening after `loadMobilenet()` has finished (because it is async)?

Comment: yep.  I have consoled every single thing even to the point of console.log(batched).  All of them returned a value until it hit that predict() function

Comment: What does `console.log(this.mobileNet.model)` give you?

Comment: Please see the screenshot in this link https://ibb.co/hMVcay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`loadFrozenModel()` returns a FrozenModel, not a tf.model, so as you can see in this [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter/blob/master/demo/mobilenet/mobilenet.js), `FrozenModel`s use execute() instead of predict()

Comment: Yeah, kinda figured that out through trial and error.  But thanks though, really helps.  I figured also that the sample image for execution needs to the same size as the declared IMAGE_SIZE.  Now just need to figure out how to pass through data from webcam